# errorexception laravel recovery foreign keys

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database

> I have 3 tables, user, Casas and Reservas , from the reservations
> index I want to get the name of the  house that is related but I get
> the following error:

```
Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object (View: 
C:\laragon\www\casaRural\resources\views\reservas\index.blade.php)
```

> And retrieve the value like this:

```
@forelse($reservas as $reserva)

    <tr>

      <th scope="row">{{ Auth::user()->name  }}</th>

      <td>{{$reserva->casas->nombre}}</td>

    </tr>

    @empty

    <h2>El usuario {{ Auth::user()->name  }} no tiene reservas en la casa -></h2>

    @endforelse
```

> casa relationship

```
class Reservas extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable=['capacidad','fechaEntrada','fechaSalida'];
    protected static function boot(){   
        parent::boot();
        self:: creating(function($table){
            if(!app()->runningInConsole()){
            $table->user_id = auth()->id();
            $table->casa_id = casas()->id();
            }
        }
         );
        }

      public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function casas(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Casas::class);
    }
}
```

> Reserva

```
   public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function reservas(){
        return $this->hasMany(Reservas::class);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> BelongsTo are singular

```
class Reservas extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable=['capacidad','fechaEntrada','fechaSalida'];
    protected static function boot(){   
        parent::boot();
        self:: creating(function($table){
            if(!app()->runningInConsole()){
            $table->user_id = auth()->id();
            $table->casa_id = casas()->id();
            }
        }
         );
        }

      public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function casa(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Casas::class);
    }
}
```